# MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch Bar - Dual-Booting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, 16.10

I bought the new MBP 2016 with Touch Bar. So far I know that Touch Bar is not available for Ubuntu users, but it is fine. I think this technology will be available in a couple of months. Does anyone tried to install Ubuntu on dual-booting on this computer? If so, does this technology work fine or not (and why)?

**EDIT :**

Knowing that I'm not talking about the Touch Bar directly. My question is rather related to the compatibility of Ubuntu with this new device. I'd like someone could explicit his/her experience so far. So, if a person has succeeded to install it, I'd like how he did it and if it works well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GAD3R: It looks like Sandra isn't asking about the Touch Bar but about getting to run Ubuntu on that MacBook in general.

Comment: @DavidFoerster is absolutely right! I'm not asking for the Touch Bar, but rather if it is possible to dual-boot Ubuntu with this new device. A lot of people said no, but other said yes. So I'd like someone could tell me his/her exper

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it's about installing Ubuntu on a MacBook (2016), dual-booting and hardware support in general while the linked question is about the Touch Bar and *only* the Touch Bar.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The indian guy posing as Sandra Ross (yep, he managed to post a photo accidentally) has been told repeatedly it is common knowledge Ubuntu, besides the touch bar, also does not recognises the SSD, keyboard and trackpad in the new Macbook even when asking if it was worth buying, and it insists in cross posting and asking ad nauseam the same questions...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/852926/compatibility-of-the-new-touch-bar-with-ubuntu  and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328044/problematic-related-to-ubuntu-and-the-new-mbp-2016 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327713/macbook-pro-2016-with-touch-bar-dual-booting-ubuntu, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327666/macbook-pro-with-touchbar-compatibility and there were more, already deleted.

Comment: AFAIK, apparently there is already an answer  "Now it works! I called Apple (the best support you could get for a macbook pro), and they help me to install Ubuntu Gnome. Now it is fine. – Sandra Ross Dec 8 at 0:53" ;-P

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: What's your point? I think this question is helpful to other people looking to install Ubuntu on the new MBP and it would be even more helpful if it wasn't closed as a duplicate of a question that deals with something else.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You have been far longer here than me to ask me what is the point of reporting uncivil behaviour and abusive crossposting...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: I agree with your assessment of the uncivil and abusive behaviour but I don't see any valid argument that addresses this question and why it should stay closed as a duplicate of a very different question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't try it myself but I did some online research nonetheless. In its current state it appears to be impossible to run Ubuntu (or any Linux) on a Macbook Pro 2016 in a useful way.

- [Apple's 2016 MacBook Pro & Linux Don't Mix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=apple-2016-mbp&num=1) (Phoronix)
- [“2016 MacBook Pro Is Incompatible With Linux”](https://fossbytes.com/linux-on-macbook-pro-2016-issue-not-working/) (FOSSbytes.org)
- [Warning: 2016 MacBook Pro is not compatible with Linux](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/5c8s1k/warning_2016_macbook_pro_is_not_compatible_with/) (Reddit thread that serves as the source for the above article)

  Money quote:

  > I have a $2800 disappointment.

  <sup>(Pun intended.)</sup>

---

I'll try to address the main blocking issues mentioned in these posts and articles, what needs to be done to get around them and how likely it is to see a solution any time soon:

- Intel graphics: Looks like some reverse-engineering will be necessary before the drivers play nicely with this otherwise supported graphics chipset …probably some proprietary Apple EFI BIOS firmware stuff. It's hard to say how soon that will happen. In the mean time there's no hardware acceleration.
- AMD graphics: AMD GPU support on Linux has been a mess since the deprecation of the Catalyst drivers but it looks like AMD is actively seeking to improve the situation and I hear that the open-source drivers are in an alright shape once support for a new chipset has been added.
- Keyboard and touchpad: Like with previous Macbooks, we'll have to wait until someone figures out how they work and writes a driver for them. I'd expect considerable interest in such a driver and it looks to be similar to existing drivers for previous Macbooks, so we'll probably see something within a few months.
- Internal SSD: The Reddit thread author reports a bogus PCI device class flag for the internal SSD while Michael from Phoronix doesn't, so this appears to be something that only affects some new Macbooks (e. g. because Apple didn't use the same model for all of them). To resolve this issue requires either

  1. a firmware upgrade from Apple or the SSD manufacturer and I don't see that happening because the issue doesn't occur in MacOS or Windows, or
  2. a special case handling in the driver in the kernel which probably requires a smallish patch that can be back-ported easily to older (but not too old) kernels.

Comment: I think there will be so modification for the next OS (e.g. Sierra) in fall 2017 according to an Apple Store Manager.

Comment: Did you try to install Ubuntu on that kind of device? According those website, I know it is impossible, but could we make modification to make this usable?

Comment: I tried to address your points in my answer. It's generally possible to “make modifications” but they won't be trivial at all, i. e. nothing that you or I can come up with over the course of a few weeks and within the scope of a StackExchange post.

Comment: I'll try to dual-boot Ubuntu by myself. If it works, I'll post a full answer of the procedure. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tried many things, but I didn't achieve anything. :( !!!!!