# Is ubuntu compatible with new macbook pro no touch bar?

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro

Many posts reflect dual boot Ubuntu on Macbook pro with touch bar has many driver problem. Does anyone know or test Ubuntu on no touch bar version?

Is any team working on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compatibility of the new Touch Bar with Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/852926/compatibility-of-the-new-touch-bar-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work in progress: https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux

btw: first result in google if you search "linux macbook pro 2016"